# Linux application monitor

Tags: linux, performance, monitoring

Is there any good applications on linux that can monitor a process and record how much cpu it is taking up and what files it has open or system commands its performing.

Can also use it to hook into the so if needed.

Free is better.

Comment: check ServerFault for many more answers to this kind of question.

Answer (score 3):

`top` in its various incarnations. Personally I like [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/). It can also show what functions the processes are sleeping in. If you need a detailed information about the functions a process calls, use `strace`

For tracking open files per process `lsof` is your friend.

Comment: also my favourite. use with guake, that gives a nice combo.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I didn't know guake yet

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [perfkit](http://audidude.com/?p=495), but it is still in development.

Answer (score 0):

This question is possibly more appropriate on server fault. However check answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449235/large-scale-service-monitoring-at-regular-intervals/). It summarizes everything I can suggest. Top should give you the CPU usage both overall as well as split up of all processes currently being executed on your system.