# Large-scale service monitoring at regular intervals

Tags: php, curl

I need to get the status of services across a large number of servers in order to calculate uptime percentages. I may need to use multiple servers to do the checking. Does anyone know of a reliable way to queue them to be checked at a specific time/interval?

I'm writing the application in PHP, but I'm open to using other languages and tools for this. My only requirement is that it must run on Linux.

I've looked into things like Gearman for job queuing, but I haven't found anything that would work well.

Comment: Suggest you expand your question to describe specific technologies you're working with, options you've tried, and constraints you're under - as it stands, the question is very broad and will likely be flagged.

Comment: Best add that kind of thing to the question (and expand it as best you can) so you don't get a slew of downvotes ;)

Answer (score 2):

Inorder to get uptime percentages of your services you can execute commands to check status of services and log them for further analysis/calculations. Following are some of the ways of doing same:

1. System commands like `top`, `free -m`, `vmstat`, `iostat`, `iotop`, `sar`, `netstat` etc. Nothing comes near these linux utility when you are analysing/debugging a problem. These commands give you a clear picture of what is going inside your server
2. [SeaLion](https://sealion.com): Agent executes all the commands mentioned in #1 and custom commands as well. Outputs of these commands can be accessed in a beautiful web interface. This tool comes handy when you are working across hundreds of servers as installation is clear simple. And its FREE
3. [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/): It is the mother of all monitoring/alerting tools. It is very much customizable but very difficult to setup for beginners. Although there are some nagios plugins.
4. Munin
5. Server density: A cloudbased paid service that collects important Linux metrics and gives users ability to write own plugins.
6. New Relic: Another well known hosted monitoring service.
7. Zabbix